# Remove border color on bar chart in D3 / Billboard.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created a table showing on it two types of data from the same sites.

Each pair is show in same color but different light ratio (e.g. dark blue and light blue).

When I print them using `"spline"`, there are two lines which look pretty but if I change the chart type to `"bar"` it adds a purple border to them which I want to avoid.

This is how my chart looks like with **spline**:

[image]

And this is with **bar**:

[image]

Do you have any ideas about how to remove that border on the second chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set below css. It will remove the border of the bar shape.

```css
path.bb-bar {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```